# phpseclib connection closed by server?

Tags: php, ftp, sftp, phpseclib

I have a pretty simple PHP script that tries to connect to SFTP server from a CENTOS 7 box. Using phpseclib via composer.

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
$usr = 'xx';
$pwd = 'xx';
$host = 'sftp.domain.com.au';

$sftp = new SFTP($host);

if($sftp->login($usr, $pwd)){
   echo "Connected.";
}else {
   echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

And even used an RSA key

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
$usr = 'xx';
$pwd = 'xx';
$host = 'sftp.domain.com.au';

$sftp = new SFTP($host);
$rsa  = new RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents("../../.ssh/id_rsa"));
if($sftp->login($usr, $pwd, $rsa)){
   echo "Connected.";
}else {
   echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

The script above with RSA actually did work a few times and got me connected. So I thought I need to understand why it works, and change a few things. I tried generating another key overwriting the existing key. But this time it didnt work anymore.

I also turned on the NET_SFTP_LOGGING with no display error just a plain "Connection closed by server". I have been working on this for days..

Only thing I could think of is when I regenerated the key and overwrite the ID_RSA somehow maybe the server thinks its not the right key anymore?

Also when I connect using WinSCP, it seems the FTP server is giving me an algorithm: ssh-rsa 4096 , sha256 and md5 code. Is this something I need to use in my PHP script to properly connect? Just trying to rule out any possibilities.

**MORE DETAILS:**

- from work I can connect to the FTP server via FILEZILLA/WINSCP
- the CENTOS box server is part of our network at work.
- I cant connect to the FTP server from home.
- on the CENTOS box I enable configured the "ssh_config" and generated keys with ssh-kegen -t RSA , I even added the id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys

Please anyone give us some advise as this is consuming me for DAYS hopefully not for weeks! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
$rsa->loadKey("../../.ssh/id_rsa");
```

Try this:

```
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents("../../.ssh/id_rsa"));
```

Also,

```
if($sftp->login($usr, $pwd, $rsa)){
```

Are you *actually* wanting to use multi-factor auth? In my experience SSH servers setup to do that are quite rare. What seems more likely is that you have a password protected RSA private key, at which point you'd do something more like this:

```
$rsa->setPassword($pwd);
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents("../../.ssh/id_rsa"));
```

Comment: Thank you for chiming in. Yes I just forgot to include the file_get_content in the post. But with your second suggestion when you do setPassword, are you refering to my generated rsa private key or is it the remote server rsa key? I always thought its for the paraphrase?

Comment: @Chopnut - in-so-far as SSH clients are concerned the remote server rsa key is always a public key. I've never heard of an RSA public key format that had a password associated with it nor would one really be necessary since the public is supposed to be _public_. So, yes, I'm referring to your generated rsa private key. Re: "_I always thought its for the paraphrase?_". `$rsa->setPassowrd($pwd);` sets the key to decrypt the RSA private key if it's encrypted. idk if your private key is encrypted or not but, in my experience, encrypted private keys are more common than multi factor auth servers..

Comment: ugh that worked. Here’s what I did. I regenerated my private key with the password of the FTP server, then feed the login both with $ftp->login($user,$pwd,$rsa). Now my question, why did it work? The only difference I did this time is use the FTP password as passhrase to my new key. Is this how I meant to generate my key with the ftp password then? Thank you neubert.

Comment: @Chopnut - first, let's verify the auth methods that you're using. If you could do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top of the file and then `echo $ssh->getLog();` after you've logged in if you could then post the log output in a pastebin.com link and then post that link here that'd be great. This'll tell us if the RSA key is even needed. I'm kinda wondering if it isn't needed. If you do $sftp->login('username', 'rightpw', 'wrongpw')` and multi factor auth isn't being employed than that'll let you login without issue. 'wrongpw'` will be ignored and will never be submitted to the server.

Comment: sorry for the late response. Bad news, when I came back to fiddling with the code and refresh the page again after a few days. Suddenly its not working again. I pretty much try to do what I did last time but this time , just does not want to play nice. What do you think is happening? Could this be their FTP server issue? I swear It worked and tested it couple of times before I left it. Now just getting so frustrated..

Comment: @Chopnut - post the logs from a bad connection attempt and we can proceed from there.

Comment: thanks for helping me out. But there is no logs, its just empty array from getFtplog, getlasterror etc. and the error just says “Connection closed by server”, I went to check the ssh2 class declaration, it seems there is an if statement that returns this error message there. My laptop broke, so cant do until Im at work which is a bummer.

Comment: guess what? Its working again. This time I only provided the password. With no key whatsoever. The behavior is very erratic and I quite dont like why it would connect and sometimes it wont. Dont want to waste any of your time. But thank you so much for the help. I will mark yours as the answer. Until I really figure out why its doing that.

Comment: @Chopnut - are you getting a line number with your error? If you're not getting anything in the logs and you're getting that error than it sounds like there's an error with PHP or your network layer. Like the first time phpseclib gives that error is when it does an `feof($this->fsock)` after receiving the server identification string. If you're getting an error there then there's nothing phpseclib can do to fix it..